# Session Issue for ASP.NET C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, load-balancing

I have just released one of my application to production environment. Live environment has two IIS Servers via a Load Balance. The server configuration people has informed that they have implemented something called "Sticky Load Balancing" to carry out the sessions to IIS 1 or 2 via the Load Balance [Sessions are handled via the Load Balance].

**Error**
On accessing the website via IE9, I am getting a view state error. Screen Shot attached.

---

[image]

---

**Exception**
The exception is not being generated from Chrome Browser. But compliance requires us to tweak the application to IE9 only.

What Needs to be done to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Remove your ViewState only use string or int variable.

Comment: I am not using any explicit View State in Code.

Answer (score 2):

The below post, although the person who asked it is not exactly facing the same situation, The solution which has been posted is valid for this, Especially the second point which says about defining a machine key for the application.

Please refer the below, i hope it helps.

[Avoiding invalid viewstate when deploying on a load balanced website without downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863166/avoiding-invalid-viewstate-when-deploying-on-a-load-balanced-website-without-dow)

Comment: I am changing the system to work with SQL Server to handle the process state. Hopefully if will aid in resolving the issue. Will revert with Feedback

Comment: Ok, all the best with that one, But if you are doing that , just to manage this issue, The above is worth a try because we are also using load balancing and have done something similar to whats being specified.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to implement the Second point in the solution. Generating our own machine key than using the ASP hashing against the Machine key name.